# How to group or label features for a specific release in Pivotal Tracker?

Tags: workflow, bug-tracking, change-management, pivotaltracker

I notice that the docs say that Epics are groups of stories, and that Releases are simply markers above and below prioritized lists of stories. I also note that we can use Epics as a kind of special label or tag to denote what can go in a release. My question is, are you using Pivotal Tracker epics to label what you WANT to go into a release, or what WILL go into a release, and why? Where in the process do you actually assign the epic label to the story?

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, I use epics to have a high level view of **relative** feature load on the team. It helps understand where time went the last couple of months.